# Windows Service with Visual Studio 2005 solution not opening with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, version-compatibility

I am unable to open a solution created using visual studio 2005 version. The solution has two windows services within. I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2010. Now I am unable to open the solution file. I have tried to open it using Visual Studio 2010 as well as the version selector, and in both cases I dont see the creating/importing solution dialogue. It just shows the hourglass for a split second and then goes away, not sure what's happening in the background, but definitely no crash indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use the project or solution file, move all classes into the new vs2010 solution and rebuild it

Comment: Thanks a ton. Why didn't I think of this?